# Output Overlapping In Opencv Output

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, matplotlib, object-detection, cvlib

I m a beginner, using OpenCV to detect objects from the image. I m using Google Colab.
Shown in the image, I got proper output with the very first image I have used.

First Output

[image]

When I Read the second Image and used detect_common_objects() method I m getting the previous image additionally the labels which I want to predict using some other Image.

Second Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the first image again (im) to draw the bounding box predictions from second image (im1). Try changing the line to

```
output_im1 = draw_bbox(im1, bbox, label, conf)
```